# How would I remove/turn Unselectable off on a page using GreaseMonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Kinda new to coding but wondering how I can remove the unselectable attribute using a greasemonkey script.

This is what I have so far.

```
var elmLink = document.getAttributeById("unselectable");
elmLink.removeAttribute('unselectable');
```

Comment: what is `getAttributeById` ?

Comment: Its supposed to select the attribute. I got it from the documentation on the site, http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Modifying_an_Element.27s_Attributes

Comment: there is no "getAttributeById" method in the documentation.grease monkey use js methods.there is no `getAttributeById` in javascript .open the console and see errors .

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a `removeAttributeById` or `getAttributeById` function in GreaseMonkey or JavaScript.

There is something close though:

You can use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find [attributes via CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

Let's say you want to find an `a` element with the attribute `unicorn`, you would have a CSS selector that looks like this: `a[unicorn]` (you don't need the element, though):

```
var element = document.querySelector('a[unicorn]');
```

`document.querySelector` will only return one element, so if you have multiple that you need to remove, you'll have to do [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and loop over all of them.

Then, you can `get`, `set` and `remove` attributes by `element.(get|set|remove)Attribute`.

So you might have something that works like:

> ```
> var elmLink = document.querySelector("[unselectable]");
> elmLink.removeAttribute('unselectable');
> ```

or if you have multiple:

> ```
> var elements = document.querySelectorAll("[unselectable]");
> Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element){
>     element.removeAttribute('unselectable');
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no such function as getAttributeByID  what you are looking for is document.querySelectorAll. you can use this to get what you want.

```
var elmLink = document.querySelectorAll("[unselectable]");
```

now this will return **EVERY** element with the unselectable attribute so you will need to loop through them to remove the attribute.

```
elmLink.forEach(function(entry) {
    entry.removeAttribute("unselectable");
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually this is what I meant.  Thanks I will edit my post for this.  Thanks.